# Render docx in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to properly render a docx file in React JS with the correct formatting, as it would appear in Word or a similar service. Currently, when displaying the text, all formatting is removed and appears as plain text. I obtain the file from the server, and process it, by:

```
const url = "http://localhost:8080/files/aboutme.docx";

axios.get(url, {
  responseType: 'arraybuffer',
}).then(response => {
  var doc = new Docxtemplater(new PizZip(response.data), {
    delimiters: {
      start: 'ran',
      end: 'ran'
    }
  });
  var text = doc.getFullText();
  setAboutMe(text);
})
```

I am using the Docxtemplater and PizZip libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Docxtemplater](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docxtemplater) is

> a library to generate docx/pptx documents from a docx/pptx template

If you need to render a docx file I think you should use [react-doc-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-doc-viewer). Then you could write something like:

```
import DocViewer from "react-doc-viewer";

function App() {
  const doc = [{ uri: "http://localhost:8080/files/aboutme.docx" }];

  return <DocViewer documents={doc} />;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure how to use that though, as when I try to return the DocViewer element in a div, similar to how you wrote, I get an error message about hooks.

Comment: @siya show me the error

Comment: Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See (invalid_link) for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at resolveDispatcher (react.development.js:1465:1)
    at Object.useReducer (react.development.js:1500:1)
    at AppProvider (index.js:41:1)
    ....

Comment: It turns out the issue was with npm (see: https://github.com/Alcumus/react-doc-viewer/issues/77). Installing it with yarn fixed the above issues. Thank you again

Comment: react-doc-viewer uses office web app in an iframe. It may not be suitable if you need to keep the documents private: https://github.com/Alcumus/react-doc-viewer/blob/master/src/plugins/msdoc/index.tsx